# Wirecard latency from Asia Region

Tags: latency, wirecard

We are using WireCard in one of our apps and recently have deployed that app in South East Asia region in Azure. We are experiencing latency with regards to the API calls to WireCard and the IP being resolved against api.wirecard.com is German origin IP (Their HQ is in Germany)

I was not expecting this at all. Has anyone experienced anything like that too? If yes, how did they worked around it? Do WireCard provides region based URLs as well? (I don't think so but I wanted to ask this).

Generally speaking, services are resolved to nearest region automatically via some kind of Geo-IP based routing based load-balancers.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the provider to ask all these questions?

Comment: I have logged a ticket with them as well but was curious about the implementation. Does not it sound strange that its connecting to a server in Germany. Thought someone had faced the same issue.